# Django Celery Invoking Periodically and Manually

Tags: django, python-3.x, celery, celery-task

I'm using Django and Celery for scheduling tasks.

tasks.py

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour='00', minute='00', day_of_week="*"))
def hello_world():
    print('hello world!)
```

In addition to running the function daily, I need to be able to invoke it manually. If a user presses a button in the front-end it will run. I could do:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour='00', minute='00', day_of_week="*"))
def hello_world():
    print('hello world!)

@task()
def hello_world():
    print('hello world!)
```

But that goes against DRY. Also, I may have more than one function that will have this same scenario. I will need to run it periodically, but also upon request.

I tried this:

```
def hello_world():
    print('hello world!)

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour='00', minute='00', day_of_week="*"))
hello_world()

@task
hello_world()
```

But that does not work. I get

> invalid syntax

I haven't been able to find this scenario in the documentation or other stackoverflow answers. They talk about invoking the function from the shell. Help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define the task twice, your periodic task can also be invoked manually with `hello_world.delay()`, so you would have:

```py
@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour='00', minute='00', day_of_week='*'))
def hello_world():
    print('hello world!')

def on_button_press():
    hello_world.delay()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that. Do I need multiple workers? One for periodic and the other for the manual? Or would the same worker  pick up both?

Comment: No, not necessarely, it will work regardeless of how you decide to split the workload

Comment: I used same worker and now I'm getting: "Received unregistered task of type 'apps.app.tasks.hello_world'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.

Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?" It's in red font is this going to eventually make the worker fail?